# session.getAttribute() is quoted with " which must be escaped when used within the value

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

I am setting a attribute to the session as:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
System.out.println(al);
session.setAttribute("arraylist",al);
```

The al is the list of `Employee` object. Also I can see the System.out is printing in the console.
But when I am trying to get the list from jsp as:

```
<%
List<Employee> employees = (List<Employee>)session.getAttribute( "arraylist" );

for(int i=0;i<employees.size();i++){
  Employee emp = employees.get(i);
  out.println(emp.getFirstName());
  out.println(emp.getLastName());
  out.println(emp.getAddress());
  out.println(emp.getContact());
  out.println(emp.getEmail());
}   
%>
```

I am getting the error:

```
Attribute value  (ArrayList<Employee>)session.getAttribute("arraylist") is quoted with " which must be escaped when used within the value
```

I am using Tomcat 6.0.33. Any information will be very helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure you're not getting the attribute from session anywhere else in the JSP? Is it *only* within that scriptlet you have posted?

Comment: Take a look related threds - http://www.coderanch.com/t/520610/vc/Help-Code-running-file-IDE and http://www.coderanch.com/t/455557/JSP/java/Error-when-session-getAttribute

Answer (score 5):

Maybe

```
-Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.STRICT_QUOTE_ESCAPING=false
```

helps. Check the more strict quoting rules.

Answer (score 3):

Use JSTL `forEach` to iterate the collection.

```
<c:forEach var="emp" items="${arraylist}">
   <c:out value="{emp.firstName}"/>
</c:forEach>
```